# Facebook android sdk needs java 1.7 to work?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I've imported the Facebook android sdk (version 4.1.1) into my project and I've encountered some errors such as

```
ArrayList<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

which throws an error that it needs **java compiler 1.7 to work**.

Then when I change the java compiler of the project to 1.7 and it gives another error that for using java 1.7 my project needs to be compiled with **android 4.4**.

So to make the downloaded facebook sdk to work I have to change it's android version to **4.4** and java compiler to **1.7** but my own project uses android version **14** which throws an error:

```
Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 14
```

what should I do to overcome this issue?? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with facebook, this has to do with the diamond operator introduced in Java 1.7

Simply change that line to this:

```
ArrayList<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

More information on the diamond operator can be found [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html).

Comment: That is 100% right , however that will only get you so far. A bit ahead in the new Facebook SDK, there are functions that are irreplaceable before 1.7, which leaves no other option than supporting only android 4.4 and newer. That is what I have figured out so far, if you disagree, explain why.

Comment: @Josh - It's not that I disagree, I just simply don't know. I don't even use the Java facebook SDK. I never have. I just recognized the issue at hand.

Comment: Well that's right @Christian.tucker , your post answers the question. I opened a new question to include how to make it work in pre 4.4 versions... and found a solution. If somebody is interested, check it out here:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140729/will-my-android-app-with-facebook-sdk-v4-3-work-on-versions-lower-than-4-4-kitka