# Will my Android App with Facebook SDK v4.3 work on versions lower than 4.4 Kitkat?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, facebook-sdk-4.0, jdk1.7

So the new Facebook SDK 4.3 is out, I am doing the ceremony to update my app.
To get rid of all the errors that pop up, I reach a point where I must step up the JDK version of my app from 1.6 to 1.7.
This also means that I must also step up my minumum Android API from 9 to Kitkat (19).
I *need* to support at least, 4.0 - 4.3 users too.
*Has somebody been able to make facebook SDK 4.3v work with Android versions older than 4.4 Kitkat(19)???*

Comment: why do you have to step up your minimum api to 19 if you dont want to?

Comment: Simply because the project will not compile, and I dont want to give up my 2.3 - 4.3 users that easily if i can find a workaround. @tyczj

Comment: well what errors are your getting, the facebook sdk should not be stopping you from supporting what you want to, let alone make you support only version 19 and up

Comment: What Facebook is and what Facebook should be are 2 different things. For example the new SDK includes this and many other methods that require JDK 1.7: GraphRequest.ParcelableResourceWithMimeType<> @tyczj

Comment: I just downloaded the sdk imported it into android studio and it worked fine, minsdk is 14. so again what errors are you getting!!

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to give up my pre-KitKat users, so I found a way to make the same old SDK compliant with facebook´s new API. No need to install a new SDK, and no need to re-implement Facebook login and authentication inside my app (Session was replaced by 3 more objects, and other changes I dont have time to change.)
So the recipe is simple, just open:

```
src > com.facebook.android > Facebook.java
```

..and change this line of code (aprox. line #87):

```
protected static String GRAPH_BASE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/";
```

to this:

```
protected static String GRAPH_BASE_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/";
```

Voila!! 
Maybe later, Facebook totally deprecates my entire Facebook SDK 3.19.1, but for today, the day has been saved.

*Source:*

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2
```